# Is this an example of a gerund or a participle?

Tags: gerunds, participles

this is my first time asking a question in ELL, so I am sorry if I broke any rules.

In the following sentence, is tapping a gerund or a participle?

> His *tapping* finger on the change mat speeded up a little when Mack
>   came in.

I thought it was a participle and that finger was the subject of the sentence, but my teacher marked it wrong. I could also see how tapping could be the subject and act as a gerund. Could anyone please enlighten me? :)

Comment: As a learner: I think whatever sped up is the subject.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are correct—and your teacher is wrong. Had it been a gerund, then it would have meant it was a finger *for* tapping (like a ring finger)—not a finger that is, itself, performing an action. But it's clear that it *is* a finger that is, itself, performing an action because it's later describing as speeding up. (Unlike a swimming pool which is a pool *for* swimming, and not a pool that is actually swimming.) However, *tapping*, on its own, can never be the subject of this sentence.

Comment: The subject is the whole NP "His tapping finger on the change mat", in which "tapping" is a gerund-participle verb serving as a **complement** of "finger".